# Zabbix: What does "Questions" mean in "MySQL Command Counters"?

Tags: mysql, zabbix

I have Zabbix monitoring a MySQL server, the `MySQL Command Counter` chart is nice, but a large portion of the graph shows massive `Questions`, Unlike `SELECT` or `INSERT`, what does `Question` mean in MySQL & Zabbix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs at http://www.zabbix.com/documentation/1.8/manual/cookbook/specific, "questions" appears to be just a total of any queries (including SELECT, INSERT, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

Questions is the sum of all queries performed by MySQL Db. Is very usefeul when you need perform tuning on data base side.